# CudaMalloc throws sigabrt error

Tags: c++, cuda

I am stuck at this Issue. The issue is with segmentation fault while doing `cudaMalloc`. This is what I am doing:

```
class AllInput {
public:
    int numProducts;
    Product * products;

public:
    AllInput(int _numProducts, Product * _products);
};

class Product {
public:
    int sellingPrice; //Ri
    struct DemandDistribution observationDemand; //C2i

public:
    Product(
            LucyDecimal _sellingPrice, //Ri
            LucyDecimal _costPriceAssmbly);
};
```

And then I have a function that creates it:

```
AllInput* in1() {
    struct DemandDistribution * _observationDemand1 =
            (DemandDistribution*) malloc(sizeof(DemandDistribution));
    // set values
    Product * product1 = new Product(165,_observationDemand1);
    //initialize product2, product3, product4 
    Product *products = (Product*) malloc(4 * sizeof(Product*)); //line-a
    products[0] = * product1;
    products[1] = * product2;
    products[2] = * product3;
    products[3] = * product4;
    AllInput* all = new AllInput(4, products);
    return all;
}
```

When I try doing this:

```
void mainRun(){
    AllInput* in = in1();
    AllInput* deviceIn;
    deviceIn = new AllInput(0, NULL);
    cudaMalloc((void**) &deviceIn,  sizeof(AllInput*));  //line-b
```

`line-b` throws segmentation fault. If I change `line-a` to  `Product  products[4] = { *product1, * product2,  *product3, *product4};` then error disappears. That is not the solution as then `products` becomes deconstructed

How does changing `products` affect `cudaMalloc`? We are not passing any argument to `cudaMalloc`, but why does it impact it?
What can I do to avoid this?

Comment: `(Product*) malloc(4 * sizeof(Product*));` should be `(Product*) malloc(4 * sizeof(Product));` or even better `new Product[4]`. Since the code following creates (likely) an buffer overrun the heap of program is corrupted.

Comment: @MaciejPiechotka Please put it as an answer, I will accept it

Comment: What possible purpose does the line before your "line-b" serve?

Comment: @talonmies none actually.

Answer (score 1):

Likely the problem is line

```
(Product*) malloc(4 * sizeof(Product*));
```

You create an array of four pointers. If `Product` is bigger then a pointer (which is likely in your example) then next 4 lines are an buffer overrun. Likely the heap is corrupted and the malloc internal data is overwritten - furthermore you could overwrite some random part of heap as well.

The line should be `(Product*) malloc(4 * sizeof(Product))`, `(Product *)malloc(sizeof(Product[4]))` or even better `new Product[4]` (note that in last case you should free by `delete[]`).